# Block someone in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

For the last week someone has been sharing an EXCESSIVE amount of porn to my account. I'm talking about 5k individual files, and 8k–10k folders filled with it. I tried removing all files, yet ones uploaded in 2016, 2017, etc. still show up, and each day the dude uploads like 200–400 more files. When trying to email them, I get a "Message Failure" response. I started researching and since 2011 this has been a problem, and I would hate to switch, but I'm getting sick of it. I tried "reporting" them to Google, but nothing happened.

How can I block this person?
EDIT - Only 7 hours later, 200 more files

Comment: That post didn't solve anything

Comment: Send feedback to Google (I added an answer to the possible duplicate with details).

Comment: @ItsYeZach That comment is autogenerated by the system.  I understand your frustration, but there was no need to use the language you used in the flag.